# how to create a cursor theme for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, cursor

I want to create my own cursor from a set of pngs. I want to know how to do it with the program: xcursogen that is readily installed with ubuntu. please give a step-by-step, detailed answer. I'm not a computer person so make it understandable, please. If you know the answer to this riddle, please don't ignore this question. i'm desperate for an answer. And by the way, i don't want to download cursors made by other people. Note that i already know how to change cursor themes with the ubuntu tweak tool that i have downloaded.

Comment: I would start by reading the 2018 Ubuntu Forums thread upon this exact topic: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384798

Comment: hey @user535733 thank you for this link but could you translate its content to a more understandable form that a non-computer person like me could understand? i've searched for cursorgen main page but i dont understand any of it!

Comment: AskUbuntu's format is intended for single-question / clear-answer. The format is poorly suited to interactive tutoring. Advice: Make an UbuntuForums account and follow up on that thread. Do a bit more research: You must learn the skills and the vocabulary for any complex task.

Comment: we could switch to chat and you can explain to me what i'm asking... could we?

Comment: i am really desperate for an explanation here. you are probably the only person out of a thousand that can explain to me this riddle. please talk to me.

Comment: Use the command `apt-cache search xcursorgen` to search for the application. This should show `x11-apps - X applications` so it's safe to assume that you need to install `x11-apps` package so run the following commands: `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install x11-apps`

Comment: However, this command should be installed by default. For use of this command, see the manpage. Simply google "xcursorgen ubuntu manpages" or run the command: `man xcursorgen` to view the manpage in the terminal instead.

Comment: the manual page explains basically what is xcursogen but does not entirely tell you how to use it. @mchid do you know how to apply the information in the manual page?